# Refreshing Cache via calling website recursively - useful?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, crontab

since few days I'm optimizing the performance of our magento (1.9) store. I mounted the var/cache folder via tmpfs with a size of 256MB.

Now my question: does it make sense to call the site via wget -m (morror) for the effect that the content will be cached? Maybe once a week via crontab?

Greetings from Munich!

Answer (score 0):

It always make sense to warmup the cache each time it is invalidated, especially if you are using reverse proxy caching servers like **Varnish** (that from my experience are tending to sometimes be flushed completely by admins/developers).

If you don't have the ability to catch and handle the event of cache invalidation, I think it's ok to **warmup critical** pages periodically via Cron.

The period of such warmup should depend on **cache ttl** and cache invalidation activity.